# How do I restore a previous version of a file?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, file-recovery

I have this file where I keep a bunch of links. I deleted one of the links for a youtube video, because the video got deleted. However, I realized I could use the WayBack machine to view the deleted video, but since I deleted the link and saved the file, the file got overwritten by a version that doesn't have the link anymore. I tried to get the previous version back, but I can't find it. This is the same file, all I did was save it, I didn't change anything else, but I still can't find the previous version. Please help. This was saved on my desktop, too, so I can't use the Cloud to get the previous version back, and this was also a .txt file rather than a Word file, so I can't get my previous version like that either.

[image]

Comment: The OS seems to indicate that no previous versions are available. It seems likely to me that there is no way to trivially get your data back. Have you considered checking your browser history (and Google service history)?

Comment: The answer is "restore from your backups". If you don't have backups... well, that's a pity. But losing a single link is probably not a high price for this lesson - you could have as well lost all your data due to a ransomware attack or a disk failure. Get this fixed ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you created a backup or have another copy of the data referenced, there doesn't seem to be a way to get it back. Backups are always very useful in an event like this, and it is highly advised you create some in the event of a similar occurrence in the future.